# Number of ways to split $N$ up into $k$ baskets such that different arrangements of the $k$ baskets are considered equivalent?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

I've been considering the problem of integer partitions and while there have been some answers for related questions, I haven't came across a solution for my following problem.

> Suppose you have $N$ balls and wish to throw it into $k$ indistinguishable baskets. Find the number of ways to do this.

Then $S_1+S_2+...+S_k= N$ where each $S_i$ ca n only take on integer values. So if $k=3$ and $N=5$, then something like $(1,1,3)$ will be equivalent to $(1,3,1)$ and $(3,1,1)$.

I've thought about [generating polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1649047/557123), and if I wanted the number of **non-distinct** ways to do this, I would take the coefficient of $x^5$ in the expansion of $(x^1+x^2+x^3)^3$, which also can be evaluated by the multinomial coefficient formula to give $6$. It makes sense as the only sets of values $(S_1,S_2,S_3)$ can take are $(1,1,3)$ and $(1,2,2)$, both of which can be permuted $3$ times.

There was another [solution to a related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/440461/generating-function-of-the-number-of-integer-partitions-of-n-into-all-distinct), and it involved the number of ways to split $N$ up into $N$ integers or less such that no two numbers are the same. For our problem, it would be the sum of the number of ways to split $5$ into $1$ number, split $5$ into $2$ numbers, split $5$ into $3$ numbers... such that $S_i \neq S_j,  \forall i \neq j$. In this case, integer partitions of $5$ into $3$ number will not be considered, since both $(1,1,3)$ and $(1,2,2)$ contain repetitions. The $3$ ways that this can be done are $(5,0), (4,1), (3,2)$.

But obviously this is not what I want as it doesn't count $(1,1,3)$ and $(1,2,2)$.

Is there a formula to do this? A related question is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/477843/n-balls-into-k-baskets-n-geq-k-no-empty-baskets), but no explicit algorithm/formula is given.

EDIT:
@marcelgoh said that Stirling numbers of the second kind would work. I have a follow-up question:

> Is there a way to iterate through permutations of numbers making up $N$, but in a 'Stirling' sense?

For instance, if I wanted to express:

$$\frac{20!}{(2*1+1)!(2*1+1)!(2*3+1)!} + \frac{20!}{(2*1+1)!(2*3+1)!(2*1+1)!} + 
\frac{20!}{(2*3+1)!(2*1+1)!(2*1+1)!} + \frac{20!}{(2*2+1)!(2*2+1)!(2*1+1)!} + \frac{20!}{(2*2+1)!(2*1+1)!(2*2+1)!} + \frac{20!}{(2*1+1)!(2*2+1)!(2*2+1)!}$$

I could use:
$$\sum_{i+j+k=5, i,j,k\geq 1}\frac{20!}{(2i+1)!(2j+1)!(2k+1)!}$$

But what if I just wanted:

$$\frac{20!}{(2*1+1)!(2*1+1)!(2*3+1)!} +  \frac{20!}{(2*2+1)!(2*2+1)!(2*1+1)!}$$

Could I use something like:

$$\sum_{i+j+k=5, 1\leq i\leq j\leq k}\frac{20!}{(2i+1)!(2j+1)!(2k+1)!}$$

Or is there some less messy notation for the same concept?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the follow-up question. My guess is that you're fixing $N = 5$ and you want to iterate through each of the $\big\{ {5\atop k} \big\}$ combinations of summands equalling $5$, for $ k = 1,2,3,4$. Is this correct?

Comment: More of I want to iterate through the summands for $n=5, k=3$. Also I checked Stirling numbers of the second kind out and it is useful to $n$ labelled elements, but what if my elements are unlabelled, say identical balls? So if let's say $n=6, k=4$, I would like to iterate through $(1,1,1,3), (1,1,2,2)$. If $n=7, k=3$, then the iteration would be $(1,1,5), (1,2,4), (1,3,3), (2,2,3)$.

Comment: Ahh okay. I believe this is $p_k(n)$, the number of partitions of $n$ into exactly $k$ parts. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) $\big\{{n\atop k}\big\}$ are what you need. This is the number of ways to partition $n$ labelled elements into $k$ unlabelled non-empty subsets.

EDIT: If we're trying to partition $n$ *unlabelled* elements into $k$ subsets, then the function we're actually looking to use is $p_k(n)$. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Restricted_part_size_or_number_of_parts), this function satisfies the recurrence relation
$$p_k(n) = p_k(n-k) + p_{k-1}(n-1),$$
with initial conditions $p_0(0) = 1$ and $p_k(n) = 0$ if either of $n$ or $k$ is non-positive.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look that up. Also, I've added an edit with a follow up question regarding notation. If you have time, please check it out. Thanks!

Comment: I tried to address your follow-up question. The recurrence relation suggests a recursive algorithm to enumerate all such partitions, but I can't think of it on the spot. I hope this helps.

Comment: Alright thank you! I'll check that out!